# How are void* pointers returned in C?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, return

Basically I need to know what register void* pointers are placed in when they are returned from a C function. I have this code:

```
void* kmalloc(unsigned int size)
{
    asm("mov %[size], %%esi"
    : /* no outputs */
    : [size] "m" (size)
    : "esi");
    asm("movl $9, %eax");
    asm("int $0x80");

}
```

which should put an address into EAX. I thought that return values in C were stored in EAX, but apparently not, (oh and I am using GCC BTW). I need to some how return EAX, register int won't work either because of the compiler settings. Is there a register that is used for returning pointers? Or is it like pushed onto the stack or something?

Comment: Write a test function like `void * myfunc(void) { return (void *) 0x20341022; }`, compile it to assembly, and look at the generated assembly.

Comment: Oh my god, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: On Intel, return values are placed into EAX, no mistake. You're probably debugging it wrong. Check the value of EAX using assembly level debugging immediately after the `CALL kmalloc` function executes. Or dump the return value to a log/console.

Comment: There is of course a chance that the inline assembler isn't doing what you expect or that the compiler inserts something else into your function that causes this scheme to not work...

Comment: This code is not safe. In the first asm, “: "esi"” tells GCC that esi was modified. That tells GCC it cannot rely on the contents of esi staying the same during the asm. However, after the asm, GCC is free to alter esi. So you cannot expect the contents of esi will remain unchanged after that point. Second, you are not returning a value. Perhaps you expect the system call to return a value and then for your `kmalloc` routine to inherit that return value, by dint of the fact that it is in the same register. However, again, GCC is free to change the register. You must return a value explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a valid way to write inline asm. Even if you put the return value in the right register, it could be lost/clobbered by the time the function actually returns, because the compiler can add arbitrary epilogue code. You must use output constraints and a `return` statement to return the results of inline asm:

```
void* kmalloc(unsigned int size)
{
    void *p;
    asm("int $0x80" : "=a"(p) : "S"(size), "a"(9));
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test code:

```
void * myfunc(void) { return (void *) 0x20341022; }
```

Compiles (with `gcc --save-temps -O2 -c test.c`) to:

```
myfunc:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $540282914, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Answer is obvious.

Comment: Weird I got the same, I guess the problem is with my interrupt handler

Answer (score 1):

You should declare how your inline assembly code returns it's result with an output constraint, like this:

```
void* kmalloc(unsigned int size)
{
   void *result;
   asm("mov %[size], %%esi\n"
       "movl $9, %%eax\n"
       "int $0x80"
   : "=a" (result)
   : [size] "m" (size)
   : "esi");

   return result;
}
```

The `"=a"` tells the compiler to move the contents of `EAX` to the result variable.

Note that i also grouped all the asm statements in one block, this way i only need to specify the input/output for this block, instead of for each statement by itself.

Compiling this with `gcc -O3 x.cpp -S` will show you the resulting compiled code:

```
_kmalloc:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    ## InlineAsm Start
    mov -4(%rbp), %esi
    movl $9, %eax
    int $0x80
    ## InlineAsm End
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

Note that the optimizer figures out that the `result` variable equals `EAX`, and thus does not need to be allocated on the stack.